# Magento 1.9 Authorize.net payment gateway

Tags: magento-1.9, authorize.net

We want to use two Authorize.net payment method on site, Actually we have two merchant account so once a limit for transaction one is achieved on same time we want to use second one, so we can disable first one and enable second vice versa..
Please suggest what is better way to achieve this , 
Can we copy the  autorize.net payment and use with some another name , if yes then how please

Comment: anyone can answer plz?